# center background image of a span in li with text centered and vertically aligned at bottom

Tags: html, css, css-sprites, centering

[image: Made with table]

I want to recreate this using CSS only instead of a table

code will be something similiar to the following

```
<ul>
<li>
<span class="icon-class icon-name"></span>
<span class="text">Text</span>
</li>
 //more li's
</ul>
```

icon-class sets image, display block, width and height, and icon-name sets position
li float left, list-style none

All of my CSS is fine except center aligning the icon; and vertically aligning text to the bottom and center aligning the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just :

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="icon"></div> Really long text 1</li>
        <li><div class="icon"></div> Text 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { text-align: center; }
li { display: inline-block; }
#wrapper { position: absolute; }
.icon { position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #aaa; margin: 0 auto;}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7

**Edit 1 :** add margin 0 auto : http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7/3

**EDIT 2 :** add wrapper and position absolute/relative : http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7/7

Comment: also, the ul doesn't need it's content centered, so just to keep up with my specific situation I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7/2/

Comment: cool, I added images for the sake of being a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7/6/ thanks for the quick response

Comment: actually, not quite at the answer I want yet: http://jsfiddle.net/efqy7/9/ I would like the icons equally aligned vertically

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/chillysheep/TXcjU/ Is this what you mean?